# Move Nested dictionary element to top level and have remaining nested elements values follow | Python | Django

Tags: python, json, django, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary, taken from a JSON file, where all of the values, including the nested values are sequential. Regardless of nesting.

```
Obj = [{
"Text": 1,
"Content": [{"Text": 2},{"Text": 3},{"Text": 4},{"Text": 5}]},
{
"Text": 6,
"Content": [{"Text": 7},{"Text": 8},{"Text": 9},{"Text": 10}]}
]
```

I need to make `{"Text": 3}` a top-level element and move all the following elements in that nested list beneath it, like this:

```
Obj = [{
"Text": 1,
"Content": [{"Text": 2}]},
{
"Text": 3,
"Content": [{"Text": 4},{"Text": 5}]},
{
"Text": 6,
"Content": [{"Text": 7},{"Text": 8},{"Text": 9},{"Text": 10}]}
]
```

Assuming, this list is really long, with a varying number of top-level and nested elements **How would I do this efficiently?**

Here is a very simplified version of my actual code, the result is roughly the same I either get empty 'Content' values or, with other (much longer) variations of this code, the order of the elements gets all out of sync:

```
Obj = [{
    "Text": 1,
    "Content": [{"Text": 2},{"Text": 3},{"Text": 4},{"Text": 5}]},
    {
    "Text": 6,
    "Content": [{"Text": 7},{"Text": 8},{"Text": 9},{"Text": 10}]}
    ]

print(Obj)
NewObj = []
lineCounter = -1
topLevelKey = -1
ElementToMove = 3

for toplevel in Obj:
    topLevelKey += 1
    NewObj.append(toplevel)
    NewObj[len(NewObj)-1]['Content'] = []
    for nested in toplevel['Content']:
        lineCounter += 1
        print(NewObj)
        if nested['text'] == ElementToMove:
            NewObj.insert(topLevelKey,nested)
            NewObj[topLevelKey]['Content'] = []
        else:
            NewObj[topLevelKey]['Content'].append(nested)
print(NewObj)
```

The end result of this code sample ends up looking like this:

```
[{'Text': 1, 'Content': []}, {'Text': 6, 'Content': []}]
```

I've tried solving this several different ways and I know the answer is probably super simple, Python Probably has a function for dealing with stuff like this, that I just can't find. What am I missing?

Comment: You can implement this using binary tree if we assume the that the node is {"Text": n} and the content will be the children of the node.

Comment: Ok I'll have to look into those. Thanks for the comment!